# Image I've appended to my div is positioned slightly outside of my div

Tags: jquery, html

I want an image to appear within my div when a link is hovered. I got the image to appear but it's appearing slightly outside of my container...can someone see what's wrong with my code?

```
<div class = "container-fluid categories">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-sm-12 text-center links">
                   <a class = "nav-all" href = "">
                       All
                   </a> 
                    <a class = "nav-nature" href = "">
                        Nature
                    </a>
                    <a class = "nav-building" href = "">
                        Buildings & Street Life
                    </a>
                    <a class = "nav-fashion" href = "">
                        Fashion
                    </a>
                    <a class = "nav-food" href = "">
                        Food
                    </a>
                    <a class = "nav-abstract" href = "">
                        Abstract
                    </a>
                    <a class = "nav-covers" href = "">
                        Artist Covers
                    </a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.categories {
height: 400px;
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid white;}


function imageHover() {
            $(".nav-all").mouseenter(function(){
                $('<img src = "cover.jpg" width = "100%" height = "100%" /img>').hide().appendTo(".categories").fadeIn("slow");
            });
            $(".nav-all").mouseleave(function(){
                $("img").remove();
            });

        }
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle for us to see?

Comment: @Swellar Everything you need is in the supplied code. The HTML in the jQuery is invalid.

Comment: @Rob I see, then I guess it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that 100% matches the 400px of the container, not 100% of the remaining space. If you know the height you'll be using for your links row, you can simply subtract that from 400 for your image height. i.e. `<img width="100%" height="380px" ... >` or something like that.  Alternatively, if you don't care for the image to be cut off, you could set overflow to hidden on the container.

Otherwise, you'll need to use a flexbox for the container and make the image stretch according to what space is available.

Comment: You are required to post your code here, not a third party web site that can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one in the future. Also, the `<img>` tag does not have a closing slash.

Comment: @Rob Thanks! I've removed the link to jsfiddle since it wasn't necessary for my answer.